# Units for effective mass

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, dimensional-analysis

I having problem how to find the right unit for the effective mass $m^
*_e$ for a electron. The unit should be in $\rm [kg]$ and  the formula is $$m^*_e=\frac{\hbar^2}{\frac{d^2E}{dk^2}} \rm [kg]$$
The units are $\hbar^2=\rm [Js]^2$ and $\frac{d^2E}{dk^2}=\rm \Big [\frac{J}{m^2}\Big ]$, so
$$
m^*_e=\rm \frac{\Big [J^2s^S \Big]}{\Big [\frac{J}{m^2}\Big]}=\Big [Js^2m^2 \Big]
$$
I know $\rm [J]=\Big [\frac{kg \,m^2}{s^2} \Big ]$ but then $m_e^*=\rm \Big [\frac{kg \,m^2}{s^2}s^2m^2 \Big]=\Big [kg\, m^4 \Big]$.

What have I missed?

Comment: Re-check the units of $k$.

Answer (score 6):

You've got the wrong units for the wavevector $k=2\pi/\lambda$: it's an inverse length $\mathrm m^{-1}$, not a length in meters.